# ¿Cómo comparar registros de fecha y hora en sql server?

Tags: sql-server

En mi consulta sale esto:

```
SELECT * FROM tiempos
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero tratar de sacar registros mediante los datos que le estoy pasando, pero NO me lista nada.

```
SELECT idtiempo,
        FORMAT(fecha, 'dd/MM/yyyy') Fecha, 
        Convert(Char(8), hora, 108) Hora, --108
        FORMAT(fechahora, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt') 'Fecha y Hora'
        FROM tiempos t
        WHERE FORMAT(fechahora, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt') >= '2015-03-24 01:29:21.000'
        AND FORMAT(fechahora, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt') <= '2015-12-25 11:29:59.000'
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema podria ser por el formato de fechas, prueba utilizando la función CONVERT de Sql server para convertir tus cadenas a fechas

ejemplo:

```
SELECT idtiempo,
        FORMAT(fecha, 'dd/MM/yyyy') Fecha, 
        Convert(Char(8), hora, 108) Hora, --108
        FORMAT(fechahora, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt') 'Fecha y Hora'
        FROM tiempos t
        WHERE CONVERT(datetime,fechahora) >= CONVERT(datetime,'2015-03-24 01:29:21.000')
        AND CONVERT(datetime,fechahora) <= CONVERT(datetime,'2015-12-25 11:29:59.000')
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenemos 2 opciones que podemos asumir. La primera es que la definicion de tu tabla es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE tiempos(
    idtiempo INT,
    fecha    DATE,
    hora     TIME,
    fechahora DATETIME);
```

Por lo que ya tendrías columnas de tipos temporales y no es necesario darles formato. Al usar la función FORMAT (la cual es extremadamente lenta y poco recomendable) estás convirtiendo tu fecha en una cadena y terminas haciendo una comparación similar a:

```
WHERE '22/10/2015 10:30:20 am' >= '2015-03-24 01:29:21.000'
AND '22/10/2015 10:30:20 am' <= '2015-12-25 11:29:59.000'
```

Lo cual se va a comparar caracter por caracter según el orden definido por la *collation* de SQL Server.

Debes aprender y recordar que las fechas y horas en SQL no tienen un formato definido. Son valores numéricos a partir de un punto en el tiempo. Por lo mismo, siempre es preferible mantenerlos en sus tipos correctos. También es importante evitar aplicar cualquier función u operación a una columna en el WHERE ya que previene que se pueda utilizar un índice y altera las estimaciones basadas en estadísticas de la columna.

Por lo tanto, la consulta puede quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT idtiempo,
    CONVERT(char(10), fecha, 103) AS Fecha, 
    Convert(Char(8), hora, 108) AS Hora, --108
    CONVERT(char(10), fecha, 103) + ' ' + Convert(Char(8), hora, 108) AS 'Fecha y Hora'
FROM tiempos t
WHERE fechahora >= '20150324 01:29:21.000'
AND fechahora <= '20151225 11:29:59.000';
```

En este caso, las cadenas de caracteres se convertirán de forma implícita al tipo datetime por tener una mayor precedencia de tipo. También es importante señalar que estos valores deberían ser parámetros o variables definidas también como datetime.

La segunda opción que podemos asumir es que tienes las fechas guardadas como varchar. En ese caso, no es necesaria ninguna conversión de la columna, en caso de comparar con variables o parámetros también deben ser tipo varchar o char que sigan el mismo formato. Pero lo más importante es que hay que planear su modificación para usar el tipo adecuado y evitar problemas por tener fechas inválidas (30 de febrero) o con formatos distintos.

Answer (score -2):

Prueba con SQL BETWEEN

```
fecha BETWEEN '2011/02/25' and '2011/02/27'
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.